# How to use the annotation in pdf files and i want to know the hightlight using java

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I need a sample or any example using java for annotation of pdf files and hightlight the particular text in pdf files using java.can anyone suggest me?

Answer (score 0):

you can do the same with the help of iText library in java. First You need to know the location of text so that u have cordinates of that text. LocationTextExtractionStrategy class in iText library will help you in this case.
And after that you can draw a rectangle or something like this at that location.

And one more thing PDF CLOWN can also be used to do the same thing. 
Here is the link to find how to do it
http://pdfclown.wordpress.com/2011/04/12/waiting-for-pdf-clown-0-1-1-release/

Comment: shall i use the itext library in android

Comment: you can use this library but there are many other factors that you will have to consider like you will have limited number of resources like CPU, Memory etc. Now you will have to check that your app is not consuming too much resources. And there can be more complexity based on your app's architecture

Comment: here i saw the sample code in your link.there is  awt tool using Draw rectangle.but android will not support awt tools.what to do.

Comment: Rectangle2D textBox = null;
              for(TextChar textChar : match.getTextChars())
              {
                Rectangle2D textCharBox = textChar.getBox();

Comment: shall i use any other java api function to draw the rectangle.is there any api for hightlighting pdf page